# Why can't I select any of the tools under "edit"?

Tags: qgis, editing

Why can't I click any of the tools under "Edit?" I want to merge selected shapefile layers together, but all of the tools under "edit" are greyed out.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  What GIS application are you referring to (e.g. ArcMap, QGIS..etc)?

Comment: QGIS. I'm trying to use Edit> Merge Selected Features

Comment: I've realised that you also have to Select the polygon too. it worked for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must "Toggle Editing" before any of the edit tools are available.

Comment: Mingfeng beat me to it by seconds!

Comment: @Alex Please upvote helpful answers and accept questions that solve your problem so the thread can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the layer you want to edit in layers panel, and select "Toggle Editting" when the context menu shows. Then the "Edit" menu will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi if you're trying to merge lines in a kml it won't work, you need to convert to another file type and then convert back (it seems)